# How to modify the Pandas DataFrame and insert new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data with information provide below,

```
df.info() is below, 

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6662 entries, 0 to 6661
Data columns (total 2 columns):
value      6662 non-null float64
country    6478 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 156.1+ KB
None 


list of the columns, 
[u'value' 'country'] 


the df is below, 

        value country
0     550.00     USA
1     118.65   CHINA
2     120.82   CHINA
3      86.82   CHINA
4     112.14   CHINA
5     113.59   CHINA
6     114.31   CHINA
7     111.42   CHINA
8     117.21   CHINA
9     111.42   CHINA

--------------------
--------------------
6655  500.00     USA
6656  500.00     USA
6657  390.00     USA
6658  450.00     USA
6659  420.00     USA
6660  420.00     USA
6661  450.00     USA
```

I need to add another column namely `outlier` and put 1 
if the data is an outliers for that respective country, 
otherwise, I need to put 0. I emphasize that the `outlier` will need to be computed for the respective countries and NOT for the countries altogether.

I find some formulas for calculating the outliers which may be in help, for example,

```
# keep only the ones that are within +3 to -3 standard  
def exclude_the_outliers(df):
    df = df[np.abs(df.col - df.col.mean())<=(3*df.col.std())]
    return df 


def exclude_the_outliers_extra(df):

    LOWER_LIMIT = .35
    HIGHER_LIMIT = .70

    filt_df = df.loc[:, df.columns == 'value']

    # Then, computing percentiles.
    quant_df = filt_df.quantile([LOWER_LIMIT, HIGHER_LIMIT])

    # Next filtering values based on computed percentiles. To do that I use 
    # an apply by columns and that's it !
    filt_df = filt_df.apply(lambda x: x[(x>quant_df.loc[LOWER_LIMIT,x.name]) & 
                                        (x < quant_df.loc[HIGHER_LIMIT,x.name])], axis=0)

    filt_df = pd.concat([df.loc[:, df.columns !=  'value'], filt_df], axis=1)
    filt_df.dropna(inplace=True)
    return df
```

I was not able to use those formulas properly for this purpose, but, provided as suggestion. 
Finally, I will need to count the percentage of the outliers for the 
USA and CHINA presented in the data.

How to achieve that?

Note: putting the `outlier` column with all zeros is easy in the 
pasdas and should be like this,

```
df['outlier'] = 0
```

However, it's still the issue to find the `outlier` and overwrite the
zeros with `1` for that respective country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice the dataframe by each country, calculate the quantiles for the slice, and set the value of `outlier` at the index of the country.

There might be a way to do it without iteration, but it is beyond me.

```
# using True/False for the outlier, it is the same as 1/0
df['outlier'] = False

# set the quantile limits
low_q = 0.35
high_q = 0.7

# iterate over each country
for c in df.country.unique():
    # subset the dataframe where the country = c, get the quantiles
    q = df.value[df.country==c].quantile([low_q, high_q])
    # at the row index where the country column equals `c` and the column is `outlier`
    # set the value to be true or false based on if the `value` column is within 
    # the quantiles
    df.loc[df.index[df.country==c], 'outlier'] = (df.value[df.country==c]
        .apply(lambda x: x<q[low_q] or x>q[high_q]))
```

Edit: To get the percentage of outliers per country, you can groupby the country column and aggregate using the mean.

```
gb = df[['country','outlier']].groupby('country').mean()
for row in gb.itertuples():
    print('Percentage of outliers for {: <12}: {:.1f}%'.format(row[0], 100*row[1]))

# output:
# Percentage of outliers for China       : 54.0%
# Percentage of outliers for USA         : 56.0%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. How to find the `percentage of the outliers` per country ? I will need that as console printout.

Comment: Added some more code to your follow up question.  Please remember to mark the question as answered.  :)